# In Paging how to show items with bigger ID first

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

On my website I'm using a paging script (see at http://www.techumber.com/2012/08/simple-pagination-with-php-mysql.html)

I'd like to get the data sorted with greatest id to the lowest id. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: you should sort your data based on descending order of `ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in sql? use the `order by` keyword and with `desc` you can sort it descending:

```
select ... from ... where ... order by ID desc
```